# Using a Progress Bar while Seeding a database in Laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I have to seed quite a lot of data into a database and I want to be able to show the user a progress bar while this happens. I know this is documented:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#registering-commands (just above)
- http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html

but I'm having problems including it in my seeder.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SubDivisionRangeSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->output->createProgressBar(10);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            sleep(1);
            $this->output->advance();
        }
        $this->output->finish();
    }
}
```

or

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SubDivisionRangeSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->output->progressStart(10);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            sleep(1);
            $this->output->progressAdvance();
        }
        $this->output->progressFinish();
    }
}
```

from https://mattstauffer.co/blog/advanced-input-output-with-artisan-commands-tables-and-progress-bars-in-laravel-5.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can get access to output through `$this->command->getOutput()`

```
public function run()
{
    $this->command->getOutput()->progressStart(10);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        sleep(1);
        $this->command->getOutput()->progressAdvance();
    }
    $this->command->getOutput()->progressFinish();
}
```

Comment: That's great you don't even need your own artisan command.  Just drop this in and it works. Thanks.  @Sevenearths this should probably be your answer since it does exactly what you had in your example without even needing a custom command.

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is my implementation code,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class MediaTypeTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $media_types = [
            ['name'=>'movie'],
            ['name'=>'channel'],
            ['name'=>'drama'],
            // ['name'=>'ebook'],
            // ['name'=>'shopping'],
            // ['name'=>'reseller'],
            // ['name'=>'broadcasting']
        ];
        $this->command->getOutput()->progressStart(count($media_types));
        App\Models\Backoffice\MediaType::query()->delete();
        foreach($media_types as $media_type){
            App\Models\Backoffice\MediaType::create($media_type);
            $this->command->getOutput()->progressAdvance();
        }
        $this->command->getOutput()->progressFinish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because you're using `$this->output` in the wrong class. If you take a look again to the article you shared, `$this-output` is used in an Artisan command class.

In fact, every Artisan command is made with the [Symfony Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) component.

You're actually trying to use it in a database seeder :)

My suggestion: build your seeders and then call them with an "install" or "seed" customized command for your needs.

Comment: yeah but the customized command is not going to be able know where the seeder is in the loop of seeding data to increment the progress bar

Comment: Of course you'll need to create something more complex, the normal seeder won't be enough :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php    
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
    
    class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Amount.
         *
         * @var int
         */
        private $amount = 100000;
    
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            // The output
            $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    
            // creates a new progress bar (50 units)
            $progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $this->amount);
    
            // starts and displays the progress bar
            $progressBar->start();
    
            factory(\App\User::class, $this->amount)->make()->each(function ($user) use ($progressBar) {
    
                // advances the progress bar 1 unit
                if ($user->save()) {
                    $progressBar->advance();
                }
    
                // you can also advance the progress bar by more than 1 unit
                // $progressBar->advance(3);
            });
    
            // ensures that the progress bar is at 100%
            $progressBar->finish();
    
            $output->write(' `enter code here`Finished', true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like effectively the same approach as the accepted highly-upvoted answer. If it has significant differences, it would benefit from an explanation of why this approach is worthwhile versus the other answers already here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across a similar scenario and is looking for a solution I created the following base class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    protected $progress = 0;

    protected function outputInfo($text)
    {
        $this->output('info', $text, 34);
    }

    protected function outputSuccess($text)
    {
        $this->output('success', $text, 32);
    }

    protected function outputWarning($text)
    {
        $this->output('warning', $text, 33);
    }

    protected function outputError($text)
    {
        $this->output(strtoupper('error'), $text, 31);
    }

    private function output($status, $text, $colour_code = 34)
    {
        $this->newLine();
        print "\033[1;" . $colour_code . "m" . str_pad($status.':', 8) . " " . $text . " \033[0m";
    }

    protected function progressDots()
    {
        if ($this->progress % 20 == 0) {
            print '.';
        }
    }

    protected function newLine()
    {
        echo "\n";
    }

    /**
     * Prevents a warning on the command line
     */
    public function testDefault()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And then used it something like this...

```
<?php

class SomethingTests extends TestCase
{

    public function testSomething()
    {
        $array = range(0, 100);

        foreach ($array as $value) {

            $this->outputInfo('Testing '.$value);

            $this->assertGreaterThan(101,$value,'101 is not greater then '.$value);

            $this->progressDots();

        }

        $this->newLine();

    }

}
```